# Dropdownlist not updating in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

In my knockout binded view even if the values binded to the dropdownlist changes still the dropdownlist is not updated. But if I refresh the page dropdownlist is updated. Everything is working fine. Data is updating in database also. But this binding is not working as expected. Dont know where I went wrong. Tried many things but nothing worked.

Here is my script file:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var gamesUri = '/api/games/';
    var developersUri = '/api/developers/';

    var self = this;
    self.games = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.detail = ko.observable();
    self.developers = ko.observable();
    self.newGame = {
        Developer: ko.observable(),
        Title:ko.observable(),
        Genre:ko.observable(),
        Year:ko.observable(),
        Price:ko.observable()
    };
    self.newDeveloper = {
        Name: ko.observable()
    };

    self.addDeveloper = function (formElement) {
        var developer = {
            Name:self.newDeveloper.Name()
        };
        ajaxHelper(developersUri, 'POST', developer).done(function (item) {
            self.developers.push(item);
        });
    }

    self.addGame = function (formElement) {
        var game = {
            DeveloperId: self.newGame.Developer().Id,
            Title: self.newGame.Title(),
            Genre: self.newGame.Genre(),
            Year: self.newGame.Year(),
            Price: self.newGame.Price()
        };
        ajaxHelper(gamesUri,'POST',game).done(function(item) {
            self.games.push(item);
        });
    }

    function getDevelopers() {
        ajaxHelper(developersUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.developers(data);
            console.log('developers' + data);
        });
    }

    getDevelopers();

    self.getGameDetail = function (item) {
        ajaxHelper(gamesUri + item.Id,'GET').done(function(data) {
            self.detail(data);
        });

    };

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllGames() {
        ajaxHelper(gamesUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.games(data);
        });
    }

    getAllGames();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Game Shop</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Games</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: games">
                <li>
                    <strong><span data-bind="text: DeveloperName"></span>:<span data-bind="text: Title"></span></strong>
                    <small><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.getGameDetail">Details</a></small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error"></p></div>
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title">Details</h2></div>
            <table class="table" data-bind="with: detail">
                <tr><td>Developer:</td><td data-bind="text: DeveloperName"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Title:</td><td data-bind="text: Title"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Price:</td><td data-bind="text: Price"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Genre:</td><td data-bind="text: Genre"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Year:</td><td data-bind="text: Year"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Add Game</h2>
            </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: addGame">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputDeveloper" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select data-bind="options:developers, optionsText: 'Name', value: newGame.Developer"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group" data-bind="with: newGame">
                        <label for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" data-bind="value:Title" />
                        </div>
                            <label for="inputYear" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputYear" data-bind="value:Year" />
                        </div>
                            <label for="inputGenre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Genre</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGenre" data-bind="value:Genre" />
                        </div>
                            <label for="inputPrice" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" data-bind="value:Price" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">Add Developer</h2>
                </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: addDeveloper">

                        <div class="form-group" data-bind="with: newDeveloper">
                            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" data-bind="value:Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try changing to `self.developers = ko.observableArray();`

Comment: @Dandy It works..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because developers must be an `observableArray`, instead of an `observable`. An [observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) is an array implementation which is able to notify when elements are added or removed from it. A common `observable` doesn't do that.